# Ignore specific path in Http.inboundGateway

Tags: spring-integration, springdoc-openapi-ui, spring-integration-http

I'm working on a Spring boot 2.7.7 + Spring integration application that works as a webservice proxy:
any URL fed to the webservice is converted to the URL of one of many third-party services following some business rules.

The accepted URLs cannot be listed explicitly. Fortunately, although the [inboundGateway documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/http/dsl/Http.html#inboundGateway(java.lang.String...)) doesn't mention it explicitly, one can actually use an Ant path pattern as parameter:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow proxyFlow() {
   ...

   return IntegrationFlows.from(Http.inboundGateway("/**")

                          ... handle/transform and so on

                          .get();
}
```

The proxy itself is working as intended, but I need to add a Swagger UI using [OpenAPI](https://springdoc.org/index.html#Introduction). Once added to the project, it provides the OAS documentation under `http://<host>:<port>/<context-path>/v3/api-docs` and the swagger ui under `http://<host>:<port>/<context-path>/swagger-ui.html`.

Unfortunately, the `/swagger-ui.html` URL is not reachable since it is caught by the Http inbound gateway, while, surprisingly, the `/v3/api-docs` isn't (it *is* reachable).

Is there a way to tell the inbound gateway to ignore this specific URL path while consuming all the other paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how that Swagger is configured for Spring, but let's see if we can make this Spring Integration stuff a bit lower in the stack. Add this bean into your configuration:

```
    @Bean(HttpContextUtils.HANDLER_MAPPING_BEAN_NAME)
    static IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping integrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping();
        handlerMapping.setOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return handlerMapping;
    }
```

Essentially, we have to override an default `0` for `order` applied in the framework.

You may also try to use some other options of the `requestMapping(Consumer<RequestMappingSpec> mapping)` to try to narrow mapping rules. If some headers or params are available for your proxy requests or that Swagger UI.

Comment: Lowering the precedence of the handler mapping solved it! That being said, I wish I could add even more points to your solution because the hint about the requestMappingSpec also proves very useful.

Comment: Seems like I talk too fast: the swagger url is now accessible, but I get a 404 error for all url paths that are handled by the integration Http inbound.

Comment: Yeah... The it is probably bad idea to catch all the paths in one controller. Consider to have it under something like `proxy/**` and rebuild target URL respectively.