# Change the precedence of the swagger-ui.html handler mapping

Tags: spring-boot, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

When using springdoc-openapi-ui 1.6 in a spring boot 2.7 project, the handler mappings for the `/v3/api-docs` and `/swagger-ui.html` urls have different precedences.

While working on a project that uses spring-integration-http, I noticed that its inbound components has:

- a lower precedence than the mapper for `/v3/api-docs`
- a higher precedence than the mapper for `/swagger-ui.html`

In other words, [in some situations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75547564/5873923), though the openapi doc is available, the swagger ui isn't.
I'll admit that the example is an unorthodox use of Spring Integration, but still, I am wondering if there is any possibility to configure the swagger ui mapper so that it has the same precedence as the openapi doc mapper.